# 'Gradle sync failed' on android studio after ejecting from React Native

Tags: android, expo

I created an app with React Native expo (expo init my-project)

However, when I ran npm run eject, there are errors when I open it out on Android Studio.

> Gradle sync failed: Java or Kotlin file
>   /Users/rachelchng/Desktop/rn/expo/decisionFatigue/android/app/src/main/java/my-project/MainApplication.java
>   does not include package declaration
>                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (9 s 805 ms)

please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `-` symbol for your package name. Try changing it from `my-project` into something like `myproject` or `myProject`.

You can also try to re-eject your expo project again and set the project name to something like this `com.domain.myproject`